# Screen goes black and becomes unresponsive after upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, 21.10

From time to time, the screen goes black and becomes unresponsive. Force restarting or closing the lid to put the computer to sleep fixes the problem. I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10 using the Software Updater. This problem was not present in 21.04 although I don't remember the kernel / drivers used in the old build.

I cannot reproduce the crash although it happens almost hourly with constant usage. The messages in `/var/log/syslog` are inconsistent between different crashes. Once the following message appeared before a crash

`kernel: [22239.387729] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun`

this error also appears in `dmesg`.

I followed the advice in

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263720

adding

`intel_idle.max_cstate=4`

in the kernel commandline but it did not fix the problem.

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 
  Desktop: GNOME 40.5 tk: GTK 3.24.30 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 41.rc 
  Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 17 9710 v: N/A serial: <filter> 
Graphics:
  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2 / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (TGL GT1)

lspci -v | grep VGA
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Tried `nvidia-driver-470` and `nvidia-driver-495` but still get screen dying / unresponsive.